# Existence of the Schwinger boson creation operator

Tags: condensed-matter, spin-models, ferromagnetism, spin-chains

Schwinger boson transformation is widely used in spin systems. It represents three Pauli matrices in the following form
$$
s^+=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^+ = a^\dagger b \, ,
$$
$$
s^-=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^- = b^\dagger a \, ,
$$
$$
s^z=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^z = \frac{1}{2}(a^\dagger a - b^\dagger b) \, .
$$
And with the constraint
$$
a^\dagger a + b^\dagger b = 2s \, .
$$
But a question arises here, how do we know such operators $a^\dagger$ and $b^\dagger$ exist and satisfy the commutation relation and the constraint? They should be represented by two matrices(not necessarily 2*2 matrices but the above relations should hold or nearly hold when restricts to two dimensional subspace. I have never seen someone write them down explicitly, so I want to know the reason.

Comment: You can check Schwinger's notes. Indeed they satisfy angular momentum canonical commutation relationships. Constraint has to be imposed separately (For example through Lagrange multiplier field in Functional integral formulation).

Comment: I do know when we write $s^+$, $s^-$ and $s^z$ in terms of two bosonic creation and annihilation operators, they satisfy the angular momentum canonical commutation relationships. But I want to know why we can written them in this way? Do these bosonic creation and annihilation operators really exist?

Comment: I am unsure if I understand your question. What do you mean by "why we can write them in this way?".

Comment: Pauli matrices can be represented by matrices in certain basis, this implies we can represent these creation operators by matrices in certain basis. In other words, we can solve these matrices by the above equations. Like any equations in mathematics, the solution of above equations may not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operators $a, \ b$ are boson annihilation operators. As such they act on an infinite dimensional space, the Fock space (for these two modes). However the sector (subspace) where

$$
n_a + n_b = 2s
$$

($n_a = a^\dagger a$ and $n_b = b^\dagger b$) at an operator level, is clearly a $2s+1$ dimensional vector space. It is made of those states for which $n_a = 0,1,\ldots 2s$ and correspondingly $n_b = 2s - n_a$.